# Build failed in AGP 8.X, Failed to apply plugin 'com.localazy.gradle'. API 'android.registerTransform' is removed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, mobile-development

I'm trying to integrate *[localazy](https://localazy.com)* into an android project with AGP 8.X version

```groovy
plugins {
    // ...
    id 'com.localazy.gradle'
    // ...
}
```

And when I try to run `./gradlew uploadStrings` I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file './app/build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.localazy.gradle']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.localazy.gradle'.
   > API 'android.registerTransform' is removed.
     
     For more information, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#transform-api.
     To determine what is calling android.registerTransform, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
```

In the documentation I did not find the possibility of integration with AGP 8.X. Are there any workarounds now?

*Now in my project I can only work with the CLI version.*

Comment: Localazy seems to be a commercial service. Why don't you ask their support?

Comment: @Robert I have a free plan. Moreover, this question seems relevant not only to me. But I'll write to them by email, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Václav from Localazy here.

We are just working on support for AGP 8+. It's a bit tricky since Google removed a lot of APIs, and they do not provide a seamless replacement.

We will hopefully release a new version soon (in a couple of weeks).